# Firewall setup for Python.app incoming connection

Tags: python, firewall

I am running a Python programme on my MacBook Pro (Catalina), but everytime it prompts the following information

[image]

However, in the pane of Security & Privacy preferences, I have set it,

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Create a self-signed certificate.

1. Open Keychain Access. Applications > Utilities > Keychain Access.
2. Keychain Access menu > Certificate Assistant > Create a Certificate...
3. Enter a name like "My Certificate".
4. Select Identity Type: Self Signed Root
5. Select Certificate Type: Code Signing
6. Check the Let me override defaults box
7. Click Continue
8. Enter a unique Serial Number
9. Enter 7300 for the Validity Period.
10. Click Continue
11. Click Continue for the rest of the dialogs

Now sign your application

```
codesign -s "My Certificate" -f $(which python)
```

In the dialog that appears, click "Allow".

With the OS X firewall enabled, you can remove the "Do you want the application "python" to accept incoming network connections?" message.

Comment: Thanks, when running the command above, it prompts a window to input the keychain password, I do not know what is it. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124591/osx-is-repeatedly-asking-for-login-keychain-password